# Focus on a textarea using a name

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea that looks something like this

```
<textarea name="target">Some words</textarea>
```

and when I'm validating my form I'm trying to focus on the elements that are filled in wrong. So I have been trying something like

```
$('textarea[name="target"]').focus();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong? I can't add an id to the textarea or a class because of how my partner is doing the php.

my full function looks like this

```
if ($('textarea[name="target"]').val() == '') {
      $('.error').html('Please let us know a small summery of what your book is about');
      $('.error').addClass('marginBottom');
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($('.className').first().offset().top)
      },500);
      $('textarea[name="target"]').focus();
      return false;
    }
```

Everything works except for the focus.

Comment: [It works](http://jsbin.com/ePEFOVIM/1/). Your problem is elsewhere. Look at the console, check that `$('textarea[name="target"]').length` is 1, etc.

Comment: Running the function on dom.ready?

Comment: yes, the function is dom.ready

Comment: this looks fine, when are you calling $('textarea[name="target"]').focus();?

Comment: That has to be in `doc ready` handler and jQuery has to be loaded first.

Comment: what browser do you run?version?

Comment: I'm calling like all the others in if statements. if such and such is blank then focus on the element. Everything else is working find in the function.

Comment: I'm running safari, chrome, and firefox.

Comment: @zazvorniki, it is better to add your full function. We have no idea where it is breaking#

Comment: @Murali There's better than asking for a full function : a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Murali I added the whole function. Everything is working except for the focus.

Comment: @dystroy I have looked at the console. As I said everything else works fine except for the focus line. It is detecting if it is empty, it is displaying the error message and it is scrolling to the top. The only thing it is not doing is focusing on the textarea.

Comment: @zazvorniki Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: Why are you returning false? If code is inside a handler, please let us know. Your posted code works so your issue is obviously from something we cannot be aware

Comment: I wonder if you have to wait for the animation to complete before using focus.

Comment: @wared http://jsfiddle.net/eL3FK/   maybe different behaviour on different browser (tested in chrome)

Comment: @A.Wolff OP has tested with Chrome too, so, my guess must be wrong.

Comment: I cerated a fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/LcJWL/ form don't seem to work within a fiddle though. And yes @A.Wolff it is inside a click function on a submit button.

Comment: @A.Wolff I dont understand your jsfiddle? my animate is working fine...

Comment: @A.Wolff You're not on the same wave length :D

Comment: @A.Wolff Then why did you create a fiddle for the animate? I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: @zazvorniki He was answering to me. I was wondering about a possible connection between your bug and the animation.

Comment: @zazvorniki That said, your fiddle reloads when clicking the button. I guess this is why focus doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @wared I think it's a glitch within jsfiddle because it's not reloading the page on my site. it does everything except the focus. The return false stops it from reloading.

Comment: @zazvorniki Try removing the animation in order to avoid this disturbing scrolling, and put an alert before and after focus (`alert(1); /*focus here;*/ alert(2);`).

Comment: @wared both alerts work fine :( so it's just bypassing it?

Comment: @zazvorniki Can you see the focus working right after the first alert?

Comment: @wared focus still is not working, but I get both alerts.

Comment: @zazvorniki Sorry I can't help.